# fullcalendar: is that a way to keep the event under the grey out area by validRange function

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

the function do this: Dates outside of the valid range will be grayed-out. The user will not be able to drag or resize events into these areas.

however, the event inside the grey out area will disappear. is that a way to keep showing the event in these areas?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible, no. If you just want to restrict dragging events into certain areas there are other ways to do that

Comment: hello, what will be the other ways?

Comment: Start by having a look at the options under the "control" section in this area of the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-dragging-resizing